Appropriate numeric treatment for derivatives of transcendental functions
Good day guys,
I was looking into the following function:
$$f = \frac{d\ln(y(x))}{dx} = \frac{1}{y(x)} \frac{dy(x)}{dx} $$
If I wish to approach this numerically, for small $\Delta x$, I can approach the derivative component as:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} \approx \frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}$$
But I cannot quite determine if it is best to take $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{y_i}$ or $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{y_{i+1}}$ to compute the full derivative $\frac{d\ln(y(x))}{dx}$.
Thank you for your insights.

The derivative of $f$ at $x_i$ is given by
$f'(x_i)=\dfrac{y'(x_i)}{y(x_i)}$. Hence, there is no approximation involved in the denominator and, in general, you should use $y(x_i)$. For small $h = x_{i+1}-x_i$, and for a regular function $y$, this choice has a small impact, but there is no reason why (without some specific information on $y$) you should use $y(x_{i+1})$.
